# Identification of a Tettigonia specimen

Tags: species-identification, entomology

At least I think it is a Tettigonia sp. but I have problems identifying it exactly because it is still a nymph. OK, it is a female, that is hard to overlook, but is it T. cantans (my guess) or T. viridissima or am I completely misled?

Found in western Germany (quite rural, Lower Rhine region, north of Dinslaken) in mid-june 2014 on a tomato plant.
[image: Lateral view]

[image: Full posterior (sort of) view]

[image: Posterior (sort of) view, closer up]

The tomato plant is a mini cocktail tomato plant and its leaves are a bit smaller, so here is an example of one with a metric measure tape aside for metrological purposes.

[image: mentioned mini tomato plant between Pementos de Padrón (Capsicum annuum) plants]